# File access exception when using IE

Tags: internet-explorer, permissions, io

When using IE browser and trying to upload file using File.SaveAs method I get **access denied** error, but in Chrome browser no any problem.

Any Idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a server problem and not client one..